# Deserialize JSON array with skipped elements

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm sending that kind of json to asp.net web api action.

```
{
  "keys": {
     "2a":["C",,,,,"0",,"0"]
  }
}
```

This json is POST-ed exactly as it is in request body to my asp.net 4.5 web api 2 action.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/TImport")]
[Authorize]
public class TImportController : ApiController
{

    [Route("")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<TImportResult> Post(TImportParameters parameters)
    {
        // parameters.Keys["2a"] got deserialized as array[3] {"C","0","0" }   :(( 
        return await new TImport().RunAsync(parameters);
    }
```

What happens is that the 2a is deserialized into array of 3 elements instead of 8 elements with null or empty elements 2 to 6 and 7.

What can I do to to desserialize skipped array elements as defaults (nulls or empty strings)?

Comment: which library are you using for deserializing? Newtonsoft has special features like nullhandling and missingmemberhandling, may be worth checking

Comment: I'm using the standard library that is used for binding arguments in asp mvc. That is JsonMediaTypeFormatter  based on http://json.codeplex.com/

I'm even unable to find out is that a reference behavior for json or a thing of particular library.

Comment: this is the newtonsoft one, check the property NullValueHandling in the JsonSerializer class you can set this to Include and try

Comment: how are you creating the object before sending? JSON.Net usually substitues `null` with `null` as default. `2a` cannot be a property name of a C# object.

Comment: I don't the json is POST-ed in body to the asp.net web api action and there is a method parameter that it is auto binding to. I will update description.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh  updated description

Comment: your input `json` is similar to what it's being deserialized to. try using http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/. But again, that's an invalid json string. JsonLint.com says **Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got ','**

Comment: Why don't you send just correct array something like that: `["C","","","","","0","","0"]`. The Web Api deserialize object correct.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh So this is a matter of json syntax. I think that this could be an eccepted answer so if you create one I will accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is an invalid json string. Though some json parsers ignore the bad syntax. And `C#`/`javascript` doesn't allow you to create properties that starts with numbers(`2a` in this case)[`JSON.Net doesn't complain though`]. A json string should contain `key/value`s separated by comma(`,`).